# Magento Skin Permission requirements?

Tags: magento-1.9

I have noticed that Permissions set in /skin folder allow anyone to access example.com/skin and view all files included in it.

Is it a good practice to allow skin folder to be visible in magento? or, should I Forbid access to everyone who tries accessing it?

Answer (score 2):

If you disable access to the skin folder, then all of your front end designs will no longer be able to be viewed by visitors to your store.

The skin folder is designed to contain design files, so yes, it's usually open to people to view.

An example might be a CSS file, such as this one, that's contained in the theme:
http://awesomesite.com/skin/frontend/bootstrapped/amazingtheme/css/ie8.css

More sensitive files, such as your local.xml file in the app/etc/ directory that has your database configuration information, should be more locked down (through permissions and .htaccess).

I hope this helps.

Comment: Fascinating. Appreciate the response !

Answer (score 0):

Just add .htaccess to the folder.

Inside skin root add .htaccess with:

```
Order deny,allow
Deny from all
```

Then inside frontend folder and any other skin folder add .htaccess with:

```
Order deny,allow
Allow from all
```